# List of Lexical and Auxiliary verbs

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I am wanting to know if anyone knows where I get a list of the verbs that are Lexical and Auxiliary. Not what the differences are, but what the actual verbs are. And maybe which are which. I've tried to find a list of them, but I just get links for how to tell which is which, but the schoolwork I'm doing is already doing that, but they don't give me a list of them.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The thing is, there are thousands of lexical verbs in English. A list of all of them wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: And this appears to be about English, not linguistics or languages in general. Probly ELL.SE would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a verb is lexical or auxiliary depends on context. The verbs which I would call auxiliary in the strictest sense are be, do, and have, when used in "he is running", "she doesn't like that", and "they have arrived". But when used in "he is", "she does sports", and "they have a cat", they're lexical instead.

Some people also call can, could, will, would, shall, should, may, might, and must auxiliary verbs, but these all act in the same way on a syntactic level, while the three mentioned before don't. So I think it's useful to have a separate name for these; they're often called *modal* rather than auxiliary.

In some dialects, ought, need, and dare can also be used as modal verbs; for me they can't. There may be other dialectal differences as well that I'm not aware of.

All other verbs (thousands and thousands of them) are lexical. I'm not going to try to list them here because there are far too many.

Comment: You seem to equate 'auxiliary verb' with 'helper verb.' On a very basic level there's reasonably widespread agreement that English auxiliary verbs are ones that display NICE properties. This would mean that *be* is an auxiliary verb in *he is.* Many, if not most grammars regard your two *do*s as distinct homophonous verbs.

Comment: @Araucaria-him It seems reasonable to me to treat the two "do"s, two "have"s, etc as homophonous, but given the way the question was phrased, I thought adding that would make the answer unnecessarily complicated. Re auxiliary verbs and helper verbs, I'm mostly taking after Adger's book on syntax, where the verbs I listed as auxiliaries have category Aux (or a more specific category like Pass) and the ones I listed as modal have category T. I believe both display the NICE properties, but Adger explains that with Aux-to-T movement.

Comment: @Araucaria-him I could see an argument for putting them all in the same category, but it seems to me that it makes more sense to consider them two separate related categories: the ones I call "modal" don't take verb-like morphology, for example, while the ones I call "auxiliary" do.

Comment: I'll have to revisit Adger. The morphology's the only thing that should make us want to split the auxiliaries into *do, have, be* on one side and the modals on the other. In every other respect (and there are many of them) *do* patterns like the modal verbs, not like *be* and *have.* For example, auxiliary *do* has no non-finite forms, must always be the first word in a VP, can't co-occur with other modals etc. I'm pretty sure Adger would view *be* as an auxiliary in *He is*!

Comment: There is one analysis which does genuinely regard (most) auxiliaries (including the modals) as only being auxiliary in certain contexts, which is Sign Based Construction Grammar as developed by Ivan Sag and others. See: [Lessons from the English auxiliary system](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331499892_Lessons_from_the_English_auxiliary_system) by Sag et al. (If anyone's interested, that is!)

Comment: @Araucaria-him Would he? I always took the "existential" _be_ as separate from the other uses (auxiliary, copula); if we're sticking to minimalism, wouldn't the hierarchy of projections forbid an auxiliary without a v? (I'm specifically talking about the _be_ in "I think therefore I am", to be clear; not the elliptical auxiliary in "who's talking? he is".)

Comment: @Araucaria-him Also, I agree that _do_ behaves oddly compared to _have_ and _be_, but it doesn't have the same semantic contribution as the modals. Adger's analysis is that _do_ is inserted at T when necessary but isn't a T itself, which is…not entirely satisfying (it's a weird exception in a system that otherwise tries hard to avoid exceptions) but I'm not sure what else to do with it.

Comment: Ah, I understood that as an elliptical copular *be* for some reason. Yes, quite so. In "There's nothing left to do but be" kind of example, that's a lexical verb. Same goes for the lexical be that's only found in questions and conditionals: "If you don't be more careful, you're going to have an accident." Re *do*: yep, *do* is arguably sui generis. [Feel free to move this all to chat if you feel that's best].

Comment: Modals also qualify as auxiliary verbs because they have the NICE properties.

Comment: _Do_, like _there_ and _it_, is inserted by rule and has no semantics. That makes it an auxiliary in my book, like _be_ for progressive. Modals are auxiliaries, too, but they're sui generis (unlike _do_, which is explicable) -- modals are operators like negatives and quantifiers; they have superpowers as well as NICE properties. As for _be_, I don't see anything where it's not an auxiliary, and **it** has lots of properties far beyond the NICE, too. _Be_ and its predecessor verbs from various roots have been an analytic problem since PIE.

Comment: @jlawler In "If you don't be more careful" or "if you be sure to ..." that *be* is arguably not the same auxiliary *be*. For example, supportive *do* is inserted for the negation there. Aux *do* is sui generis to the extent that its grammar is very different from *be* and *have* on one side and the modals on the other. So for example, it has no non-finite forms (apart from, depending on which church you pray at, its use in imperatives) like the modals, but inflects for person like the participle-taking auxiliaries. Of course, *be* is odder than odd too.

Comment: I would ?* _If you don't be more careful_ -- I prefer _If you're not more careful_. Something closer might be _Do be a "Do Bee"; don't be a "Don't Bee"_, which is playing with the categories for children's amusement (and potentially edification, though I doubt it).  Do-support _do_ is inserted by rule and has no meaning, but it's perfectly verbal in that it inflects (which is, after all, its main purpose), contracts, and inverts. That's all it needs to do, like any good driveshaft. The cargo is in the lexical carriages.

Comment: @jlawler How about "If you don't be quiet, ..."?

Comment: At that point I'd say "if you don't shut up". _Be quiet_ as an imperative is fine, but that's as active as I can get.

Answer (score 3):

This question might be a better fit on EL&U or ELL. However, I'd like to provide a different answer to the one already posted here.

The class of auxiliary verbs in English is a closed class of verbs with a dozen or so central members and a few marginal or defective ones. If you know what these verbs are, then you effectively know that every other English verb is a lexical verb.

It was once the case that 'auxiliary verbs' were seen to be verbs that always appeared before another verb, which would exclude the verb *be* for example in:

- he's ill

but might include *get* in:

- he got fired

However, most mainstream grammars,  for example *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (Aarts 2011), now recognise auxiliary verbs to be those verbs that display NICE properties. These relate to data like the following, where an asterisk, *, indicates an ungrammatical example:

- Negation: *They like not cheese. / They **do** not like cheese.
- Inversion: *Like you some cheese? / **Would** you like some cheese?
- Code: *Yes, I would like. <s>some cheese</s> / Yes, I **would.** <s>like some cheese</s>
- Emphasis: A: You don't eat cheese! B: <sup>?</sup>I *eat* cheese! / I ***do*** eat cheese!

The verbs that take part in such constructions in English are:

- be, have
- do
- can/could, may/might, shall/should, will/would, must

There are also some marginal members that can only occur in some environments, or are only auxiliaries for some speakers:

- need, dare, ought, used, better

Note that auxiliaries do not have to be followed by another verb in such analyses. So the verb *be* is always an auxiliary.

It's also useful to note that there are two different verbs *do*. The auxiliary that we find in *Do you like cheese?* and the lexical verb which we find in sentences like *What have you **done** to my lasagne?*. Likewise there is an auxiliary *have*, as in *I have finished* and a lexical verb *have* as in *I had a party*.

All the verbs not listed above are lexical verbs.

Comment: I would add _get, come,_ and _go_ to the marginal group. And there's lotsa novel combinations like _wanna, useta, gotta,_ etc. that are gonna be Official auxiliaries some day.